# Reverse relationship of 1 / x?

Tags: javascript

Right now this function console.logs `.1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1`

I am looking for a way to reverse this, so it logs `1 .9 .8. .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1` instead. You can see my attempt, which is commented.

```
function blah(size) {
    for (var x = 1; x <= size; x++) {
        var alpha = (1 / size) * x;
        //var alpha = (1 / x) * (1 / size)
        console.log(alpha);
    }
}

blah(10);
```

Comment: `for (var x = size; x > 0; x--) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either reverse the loop

```
for(var x = size; x >= 1; x--) {
```

or change your formula

```
var alpha = 1 - ((x - 1) / size);
```

I think it's most idiomatic for a loop to start at `0`, and to have index `i`, so I would probably do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  var alpha = 1 - (i / size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the direction of your loop:

```
for (var x = size; x >= 1; x--) {
```